# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editText')

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editText')

when I am trying to call my function which is also returning a variable.

```js
try {
    let editedText = [];
    editedText = this.editText(textOrig); // HERE I AM CALLING editText();
    // push changed text to array
    console.log("Saved edited text" + editedText); 

    row.values[RM.Data.Attributes.PRIMARY_TEXT] = editedText; 
    toSave.push(row);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(' can not be transformed because of error: ' + err.message);
}
});
```

And this is the function which I am calling:

```js
editText(text) {

    let editedText = text;
    console.log("Inside edit text function");

    const regexFont = /font-size:+([1-9]|[1-9][1-9]|[1-9][1-9][1-9]|[1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9])+pt/g;
    const regexLi = /((<li id="_)+([1-9][0-9]*)+">)/g;
    const regexUl = /((<ul id="_)+([1-9][0-9]*)+">)/g;
    const regexOl = /((<ol id="_).*?(">))/g;
    const regexCol = /((<span style="color:).*?(">))/g;
    const regexFontT = /((<span style="font-family:).*?(">))/g;
    const regexBackgroundC = /((<span style="background-color:).*?(">))/g;
    const regexMargin = /(((<p id=").*?(style="margin-)).*?(">))/g;
    const regexTextAlign = /(text-align:).*?(;)/g;
    const regexHeaders = /((<h\d id=").*?(">))/g;
    const regexHeadersEnd = /<\/h.>/g;

    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('<b>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</b>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('<i>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</i>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('<u>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</u>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('<del>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</del>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('<sup>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</sup>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('<sub>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</sub>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexLi, '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexUl, '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexOl, '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexCol, '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexFontT, '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexBackgroundC, '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexMargin, '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexTextAlign, '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexHeaders, '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexHeadersEnd, '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</p>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</span>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</p>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</li>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</ul>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll('</ol>', '');
    editedText = editedText.replaceAll(regexFont, 'font-size:10pt');

    return editedText;
}
```

I tried make it async also use `#` and use `=>` but it is not working. I am expecting that the function will be called successfully and I will get that returned variable.

Comment: I don't think you need the this. before your call to editText.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. Where is `editText` defined, exactly? What is the value of `this`?

Comment: How are you calling the first code? You're using `this`, so it should be inside an object method.

Comment: Tangential, but maybe consider using an HTML parser w/ whitelisting etc.